# AS3: http web requests from flash are timing out or or never "returning"

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, httpwebrequest, timeout

I run a facebook game that makes http web requests to my server using AS3's URLRequest and URLLoader classes, then takes the json data that the server spits back and and processes it it, etc etc..

Lately I've had users complaining about server requests that never come back. They perform and action and the game just kinda hangs there waiting for a response indefinitely. If it were just every now and again I would blame it on the server just dropping the ball every so often, but some users complain about having this problem consistently at the same exact spot, while others don't get it at all.

The part that bothers me the most is that no matter what I do I cant reproduce the issue that they are having. How can I diagnose this issue without being effected by it? I'm stumped.

Do you guys have any idea what might be going on, or anything that I can do to get more information on what might be happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your server script is getting data it doesn't like and crashing under certain circumstances (could be anything like bad characters in a string). The script dies and the request returns nothing. You could try wrapping your server script with an error handler that catches and logs unexpected errors and returns a status code to the client so you know what's going on rather than the connection simply being severed.

If it's hanging though the issue could be an infinite loop in the code which will be harder to catch. You may need to raise and handle timeouts in some way that allows for dumping debugging information.